# Single Git Repo for Client and Server?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have two git repos right now. The first is a server-side app that prepares data and the second is a mobile app that consumes it. They are very different apps but they interact; that's why they are currently in two different repos and it's why I think they should be under the same parent.

I don't want to use submodules for this because I'd prefer not having multiple steps to keep things in sync. Maybe it's because I'm just not enough of a git ninja. Anyhow, what I'd like is a structure like this:

```
root -+
      - client
             + lots of stuff
      -server
             + lots of stuff
```

and I'd like to be able to clone either client or server or the whole thing.

Is there any way to do this or am I trying to fit a square peg into a round hole?

Comment: good question.  Wondered about that myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better if they are in two separate repo.
If you are using github its better if it is separated so that github can understand you repository better. This means github can classify what kinds of languages are you using in your code.

Also, having two separate repo is good so you can better manage the specific needs of the projects in the repo. They are two different platforms, I assume. So it would be wise to separate them. Having them in the same repo is not that organised.